# Change compatibility mode of shortcut link using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to set the compatibility mode of a shortcut link using delphi 2010 code. Is this possible?

We sometimes create shortcuts with

```
procedure createShortcut2(const AFilePath, AArguments: String; shortcutbasename: string='');
```

If we can do change the compatibility mode in our existing code that would be great, however, 
if we have to set the value of on existing shortcut link file, then that  would work as well.

Comment: AFAIK, changing compatibility mode of a shortcut actually changes the compatibility mode of the target file. I don't know of any API for this, but the info is stored in the Registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`.

Comment: Actualy, that is my overall goal is the change the compatbility mode of the file, So when the shortcut is created, it can then be run in that particular mode.

Comment: @kobik is correct, I believe, there's no api for this (reference (kind of): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/11/9976571.aspx ). Just write to the registry with the full path, any shortcut that refers to it or that will refer to it will launch the app in compatibility mode.

Comment: With regards to the registry entry, you need to add a key with your link target's fully qualified pathname (`AFilePath`, if I'm reading your code correctly), with a string value of `WINXP`. If you need admin rights, use `RUNASADMIN`, and if you need both it's `RUNASADMIN WINXP`. (For other compatibility flags, you'll need to look at that registry key; mine only has three values - the two above, and the entries for the Delphi IDE for `ELEVATECREATEPROCESS` for debugging.)

Comment: The Old New Thing article explains why there's no API. Because this switch is intended to be controlled by the user. So perhaps there's a better solution to your underlying problem. But we don't know what that problem is.